# unable to see deployed functions in firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

***Issue:***

I'm new to Node.js and unable to see deployed functions from firebase. I do hav confirmation that my function is deployed along with the function URL. Below is my index.js.

***Code***

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase and browniePointsBeta!");
});

exports.sendPushNotifications = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send("Attempting to send push notification....")
    console.log("Logger --- trying to send push notification....")

    var fcmToken = "dlwIIdEGtzY:APA91bEckWNnjW_D7vOB1ipwYTkOMAOJSdnOmyafCZ5MN5eGoZtx02PnYbJ2LGxfXWyR6Nx3zKvUqyb8N6atk8Z-oFEWsJYyvrd74AvIr0dMmvwlYHRxYz5PpXZ5iFW26H4ZJ2PQ8paa";

    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Push notification title here!",
            body: "Body of push notification here!"
        }
    };

    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload)
        .then(function(response) {
            // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
            // the contents of response.
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            // return true
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            // return true
        });
})
```

Comment: Could you be more clear about what it is you're expecting to see after you deploy?

Comment: A notification display on my mobile device.

Comment: So you can see it in the console, the function invokes, but you don't get the message you're looking for?

Comment: That is correct sir. Also is there any reference on this subject I can lookup?

Comment: I think you'll have to debug your function, token, and mobile app, all at the same time.

Comment: I was able to test the mobile side and the FCM Token. So I am fairly confident that it is functional.

Comment: If you suspect a bug, you could contact Firebase support for assistance: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Will try thank you.